# Transparent background in LaTeXiT using the Beamer class

Tags: beamer, latexit

I want to typeset math in LaTeXiT in the same way it appears in Beamer.  To be consistent with my Beamer presentation, I use the following preamble in LaTeXiT:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

I believe the typeset is fine, for example typesetting

```
A
```

seems to work, however there is a small but annoying white background behind "A"; how do I get rid of it, i.e. how do I get a transparent background in LaTeXiT when using the Beamer class?

Comment: Do you mean you're pasting the LaTeXit output intto your Beamer presentation? Why not directly coding in the LaTeX file?

Comment: The default `beamer` theme has a white background. By the way, `times` is deprecated.

Comment: I know, it's just that I think LaTeXiT is supposed to output transparent backgrounds by default; why is it not working here?  @egreg I paste the LaTeXiT output into another program for further processing before including the final image in Beamer.

Answer (score 2):

As cfr mentioned in the comments the default `beamer` theme has a white background. To get a transparent background it has to be reset. Just add

```
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{bg=}
```

to the preamble in LaTeXiT.